# in Apache spark, i can't use static phrases in Scala

Tags: apache-spark

```
scala> val streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream.
     schema(staticSchema).
     option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).
     format("csv").
     option("header", "true").
     load("/home/server/spark/data/csv/example/*.csv")
```

:24: error: not found: value staticSchema
       schema(staticSchema).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPoNt.png)
              ^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
:24: error: not found: value staticSchema schema(staticSchema).
```

the above error is coming because you have not declared staticSchema, declare it first and use.

And the issue describe in Image is different, which state that `"error: not found: value staticDataFrame"`

it gives error because you haven't used `val` keyword before staticDataFrame.

[image]

Comment: I've applied for you to LinkedIn LinkedIn! my ID is tjdwp0728@naver.com~!